# Specific preg_replace issue - taking a parameter from the search pattern and plugging it into replacement pattern?

Tags: preg-replace

Ok, how would I do something like this... if I have a replacement pattern called:

```
$replacement = '<div class="coupon"><input type="text" value="" /></div>';
```

and I'd like to search for all cases of either:

```
<input type="text" size="15" name="coupon" id="coupon" />
```

or

```
<input type="text" size="15" name="coupon" id="coupon" value="xyz" />
```

and if found, replace that with the $replacement variable, except that if found the match like in the 2nd case, how would I take out the xyz value from "value" parameter in that input field and plug it into the $replacement's value parameter so that in the end I get this as the $output value:

```
<div class="coupon"><input type="text" value="xyz" /></div>
```

(in case the original input field had xyz as the value, and if not then the value would be empty)

Is that even possible?

And I probably need to run two of these preg_replace statements to make this happen for both cases, so this one as the first one kinda works:

```
$output = preg_replace('<<input type="text" size="15" name="coupon" id="coupon" />>', $replacement, $output);
```

but how do I do it for the second one?

or is there a way to write it all as one statement that covers both conditions?

I'm just lost here.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this a couple of different ways.  If you're wanting to use the variable `$replacement` that you created, you can use `preg_replace_callback` to do that.  But it would be far simpler to just use it in the expression like this:

```
// CREATE AN EXAMPLE STRING
$string = '<input type="text" size="15" name="coupon" id="coupon" value="xyz" />
<input type="text" size="15" name="coupon" id="coupon" />';

// DO THE REPLACEMENT
$string = preg_replace('~<input type="text" size="15" name="coupon" id="coupon"( value="([A-Z0-9]+)")? />~i', '<div class="coupon"><input type="text" value="$2" /></div>', $string);
```

This will output the following:

```
<div class="coupon"><input type="text" value="xyz" /></div>
<div class="coupon"><input type="text" value="" /></div>
```

[Here is a demo of the REGEX](http://regex101.com/r/nJ6jV9)

Comment: somehow I couldn't get that to work.. re-read my edited question, maybe you missed something, or maybe I missed something in your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I don't understand then.  When I run the code above, I get exactly what it seems to me like you are wanting.  Here is a [working demo of the code above and what it outputs](http://ideone.com/aESuE7).  As best I can tell, that is exactly what you are looking for.  Are you maybe using different code for your real-world application than you put in the post?  If so, I can take a stab at it with your real-world code instead of your test code.  The principles should be the same for any input string, though.

Comment: actually now that I've gone through that example, yes, this is exactly what I needed. Thank you!